# How to get cardinal number of an amount using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numbers

I have a pandas dataframe like as shown below

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'amount':['150k','210k','41M','61M','81K','101m','121k']})
```

I would like to get the cardinal number for the amount in the dataframe

For ex: 150k should be 150000, 210k should be 210000 etc

I tried the below but it doesn't work and not accurate enough

```
data['amount'] = data['amount'].replace(['k',,'K','m','M'],['000','000','00000','00000'])
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below. I would like to have stable and efficient appraoch. If I replace, I might make mistakes wrt to number of zeroes

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without regex:

```py
>>> data["amount"].str[:-1].astype(int) \
      * data["amount"].str[-1].str.upper().map({"K": 10**3, "M": 10**6)

0       150000
1       210000
2     41000000
3     61000000
4        81000
5    101000000
6       121000
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `regex=True`

```
data['amount'].replace(['k','K','m','M'],['000','000','00000','00000'],regex=True)
Out[169]: 
0      150000
1      210000
2     4100000
3     6100000
4       81000
5    10100000
6      121000
Name: amount, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted...But is that the only way to do this? I mean only regex replacement is available? Is there any other approach to do this replacement?